# Cannot sent mail in Mimekit

Tags: c#, email, .net-4.5, mimekit, mime-message

While sending the mail from c# using the below code of MimeKit

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(FromAddress, "Notification"));
            

foreach (var address in Toaddress.Split(','))
{
  message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(address.Trim(), ""));
}
message.Subject = Subject;

message.Body = new TextPart("plain") { Text = "Test Message" };

using (var client = new SmtpClient())
{
   client.Connect(EmailHostName, Portnumber, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
   client.Authenticate(UserName, Password);

   client.Send(message);
   client.Disconnect(true);
}
```

I get the below exception

```
MimeKit.ParseException: Invalid addr-spec token at offset 0
   at MimeKit.InternetAddress.TryParseAddrspec(Byte[] text, Int32& index, Int32 endIndex, Byte[] sentinels, Boolean throwOnError, String& addrspec, Int32& at)
   at MimeKit.MailboxAddress.set_Address(String value)
   at MimeKit.MailboxAddress..ctor(Encoding encoding, String name, String address)
   at MimeKit.MailboxAddress..ctor(String name, String address)
```

I had tried different solutions from Internet but neither worked, Anyone please help to solve the issue

Tried Solutions:

[Unable to parse tnef part from MimeMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57723626/unable-to-parse-tnef-part-from-mimemessage)

[https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/MimeKit.InternetAddress.TryParseLocalPart(byte[],%20ref%20int,%20int,%20bool,%20out%20string)/](https://www.csharpcodi.com/csharp-examples/MimeKit.InternetAddress.TryParseLocalPart(byte%5B%5D,%20ref%20int,%20int,%20bool,%20out%20string)/) (No use)

https://www.nopcommerce.com/en/boards/topic/90019/email-error-invalid-addr-spec-token-at-offset-0-v43 (No Use)

**Edit:**
The issue is because of `message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(FromAddress, "Notification"));` it is in wrong order so changed to `message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Notification",FromAddress));`to over come the error

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what have you tried? And what addresses you provide (some examples) when running this code?

Comment: Have you debugged `FromAddress` and `Toaddress` checking that they are/contain valid email addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just have your MailboxAddress ctor arguments in wrong order.

https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit/blob/master/MimeKit/MailboxAddress.cs#L163

```
public MailboxAddress (string name, string address) { ... }
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked, but there is a new exception `"The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected."` which needs the configuration of SMTP to be changed